# error in strpdate2num converter in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to read from file a datetime string followed by some data. It provide error. I reduced it to following task which produces error

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.dates import strpdate2num
from io import StringIO 

d = StringIO(u'16-03-13 20:13:55')
date = np.loadtxt(d, converters={0:strpdate2num('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')})
date
```

provides following error:

```
ValueError: time data '16-03-13' does not match format '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

execution of separate parts works well

```
d = StringIO(u'16-03-13')
date = np.loadtxt(d, converters={0:strpdate2num('%y-%m-%d')})
date
```

gives me

```
array(736036.0)
```

the piece alone with time works also well

```
d = StringIO(u"20:13:55")
date= np.loadtxt(d, delimiter=' ', unpack=True, converters={0: strpdate2num('%H:%M:%S')})
date
```

gives

```
array(693596.8429976852)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because `np.loadtxt` is trying to split your string up into two components, as its default delimiter is a space and you have a space in your string.

If you change the delimiter to anything else, this will work, for example:

```
date = np.loadtxt(d, converters={0:strpdate2num('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')}, delimiter=',')

print date
# 736036.842998
```

Of course, if you have data after your string, and your delimiter is a space between the datetime string and the data, you may need to read the date and time as two separate strings, then join them together after.