# load txt with datetime

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

Good morning,
I'm really new to python, I'm trying to load datatime into python. I have found various options but none correctly respond to the problem.
I see this code but it's not workin obviously, "since strptime () takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)"

```
from datetime import datetime
data2012 = numpy.loadtxt("C:\\Users\\...\\onde_corr_2012.txt", converters={0:datetime.strptime('%m/%d/%y  %H:%M:%S')}, delimiter=',')
```

The txt file has this structure:

```
01-01-2012 00:00,0.36,-3.42,0.76
01-01-2012 00:30,0.35,-3.45,0.75
01-01-2012 01:00,0.35,-3.42,0.76
01-01-2012 01:30,0.36,-3.43,0.76
01-01-2012 02:00,0.36,-3.44,0.75
...
```

Comment: What is `loadtxt`? The error message itself is clear: `strptime` expects two arguments, like so: `datetime.strptime("2020", "%Y")`.

Comment: Perhaps `converters` should be a dictionary of functions, like `{0: lambda s: datetime.strptime(s, '%m/%d/%Y  %H:%M:%S')}`.

Comment: Thanks, I just made your suggestions but the problem remains. I wanted to apply what reported here: << https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976215/error-in-strpdate2num-converter-in-matplotlib >> but strpdate2nume doesn't exist in matplotlib.dates so i found strptime but I can't apply it in loading data

Comment: For a date/time string with format like `01-01-2012 02:00`, the correct strptime code would be `'%d-%m-%Y %H:%M'` (assuming day comes first; adjust order if needed). By the way, you might want to have a look at `pandas`, for table-like data like these.

Comment: You're trying to load different dtypes in a numpy array. You definitely can do this with `structured` array. But most straightforward way is to load it into pandas with `pd.read_csv()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
from datetime import datetime
data2012 = np.loadtxt("try.txt", converters={0:lambda t: datetime.strptime(t.decode(), '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M')}, delimiter=','
                      , dtype={
                            'names': ('time', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3',),
                            'formats': ('datetime64[m]', 'float', 'float', 'float')
                                }
                     )

data2012
array([('2012-01-01T00:00', 0.36, -3.42, 0.76),
       ('2012-01-01T00:30', 0.35, -3.45, 0.75),
       ('2012-01-01T01:00', 0.35, -3.42, 0.76),
       ('2012-01-01T01:30', 0.36, -3.43, 0.76),
       ('2012-01-01T02:00', 0.36, -3.44, 0.75)],
      dtype=[('time', '<M8[m]'), ('col1', '<f8'), ('col2', '<f8'), ('col3', '<f8')])
```

or:

```
df = pd.read_csv("try.txt", header=None, date_parser=[0])
df
                  0     1     2     3
0  01-01-2012 00:00  0.36 -3.42  0.76
1  01-01-2012 00:30  0.35 -3.45  0.75
2  01-01-2012 01:00  0.35 -3.42  0.76
3  01-01-2012 01:30  0.36 -3.43  0.76
4  01-01-2012 02:00  0.36 -3.44  0.75
```

Comment: thank you very much, I was hoping not to use pandas but it is so fast and intuitive that I will use it more often.
The solution with np.loadtxt "saves" each line as text, thus impractical when manipulating the data.
Thanks a lot again to everyone.